# Sitecore CMS User Login/Logout Info?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

Is there any way we can find out who logged in and logged out in Sitecore CMS, with the timestamp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also see some of the information in the log file. Here it is possible to see when people logged in, but not when they logged out, as this can be triggered by a timeout.

If you look in your log file you should see something like this:

```
9004 10:10:14 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Login
```

I would recommend that you use the [Sitecore Log Analyzer](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx). It will be much easier to get an overview there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if something exist out of the box for showing when user loggedin/logout.
You can look to classes for next processor with .net Peek  and check how they are working,extended and write to logs file.

> ```
> <loggingin argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.LoggingInArgs">
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.ClearCache, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckClientUser, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckStartPage, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
> </loggingin>
> <logout argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.LogoutArgs">
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.ClearCache, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.CheckModified, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.ClearSession, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.RemoveTicket, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
>    <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.GotoLogin, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
> </logout>
> ```

You need to extend or better to add new processors after:

```
  <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckStartPage, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

for loggin, and

```
 <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Logout.GotoLogin, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

for logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information in Sitecore log file under data folder, please see below path to reach data folder -

\Data\logs

under this path choose log file according to time and in the log file you can see information about user that who logged in and what update user made with timestamp.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?